# Why am I getting this VBScript "Overflow" error?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Intermittently I am getting "VBScript runtime error '800a0006': Overflow" on this line:

`Response.Cookies("AffiliateID").Expires = Date() + 30 '30 day cookie`

The error message is referencing this line but maybe it is happening in the code around it, which follows:

```
 elseif Session("LoggedIn")<>1 and not isEmpty(request.querystring("aff")) then
    Dim arr_service_area_options, c
    arr_service_area_options = Split(Application("SERVICE_AREA_OPTIONS"),",")
    for c = 0 to UBound(arr_service_area_options)
        if CInt(Trim(request.querystring("aff"))) = CInt(Trim(arr_service_area_options(c))) then
            Session("AffiliateID") = arr_service_area_options(c)
            Response.Cookies("AffiliateID") = arr_service_area_options(c)
            Response.Cookies("AffiliateID").Expires = Date() + 30 '30 day cookie                    
            exit for
        end if
    next
```

Comment: Check for any code that could throw a Divide by Zero error nearby

Comment: "maybe it is happening in the code around it?" We can't tell unless you show us the code around it! Also does the AffiliateID cookie exist in the request you're working with?

Comment: I never figured this out, so I refactored that code out, since it was terrible anyway :)

Comment: If you are running either Windows Server 2003 x64 or Windows XP x64 you may be affected by a fault in the C++ Runtime library and can download a hotfix from Microsoft. For further details, refer to Microsoft KB955536 - [VBScript throws a floating-point exception when the C runtime returns a stale floating-point status flag in a Windows Server 2003 environment](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955536).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line to

```
Response.Cookies("AffiliateID").Expires = DateAdd("d", 30, Date()) '30 day cookie
```